# how can i test a button-click with an JavaScript confirmation with Arquillian?

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jsf-1.2, jboss-arquillian

i'm testing my JSF with Arquillian.

a simple button looks like this:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  <a4j:commandLink value="delete" 
   ajaxSingle="true" id="delete"
   action="#{controller.delete(object)}" 
   reRender="something" status="globalStatus" 
   onclick="if(!confirm('do you really wanna delete this?')){return false;}" />
</h:form>
```

The controller-function will looks like this

```
delete(Object object){ 
  do something 
}
```

My test looks like this

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestCategoryPage extends Browser 

@Test
@RunAsClient
public void delete_test(){
browser.open(URL);
browser.click("id=myForm:cbDelete");
Assert.assertTrue("something", browser.isElementPresent("xpath=//p[contains(text(), 'deleted successfull')]"));
```

All other tests are working, but when i run this test i get the following exception:

> com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: There was an
>   unexpected Confirmation! [do you really wanna delete this?] at
>   com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:112)

Is there any way to catch this javascript confirmation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, basically I use jsexecutor to handle 'bottlenecks'  with js:

```
//jsCLick on element function:

public void jsClick(String cssSelector){
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssSelector+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

taking into condiration post by Prashant Shukla he suggested you proper idea you can act in the following way:

```
public void jsAlertHandle(){
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append("window.confirm;");
            stringBuilder.append("window.confirm = function(m) { return true; };");
            js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
}
jsAlertHandle();
```

Hope now a this becomes more clear to you)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to look at Arquillian Graphene: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQGRA/Getting+Started

Graphene has built in support for ajax waits. Works as a wrapper around the Selenium APIs.

Comment: alright, i will have a look on Graphene, but i really hoped that there is already a function in Arquillian or Selenium which i just don't know yet!

Comment: `Selenium.waitForCondition(javascript, timeout)` is what Graphene use in the background. Add some 'random' javascript that can detect when the ajax call is done.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a confirmation pop up before the 'deleted successfull' message. If thats the case you need to handle the alert pop up. try following

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Or you can use javascript executor ot override the confirmation box:

```
js.executeScript("window.originalConfirm = window.confirm;window.confirm = function(m) { return true; };");
```

Comment: any way to do it without the webdriver?
and what you mean with js.???  where is the js. from?